# Getting Data Items from MySQL database using AJAX, PHP and JSON

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I'm stuck getting my AJAX/PHP to work. I'd really appreciate it if someone can help me to spot the error(s) I'm making.

Here's an extract from my first file which successfully populates the select in the HTML:

```
<?php
include 'connect_db.php';
//get all period types data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM periodtypes ORDER BY period_type_id";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);?>
```

The HTML/PHP for the select:

```
        <select id="period_type_id" name="period_type_id" onchange="getNewP();">
        <option value="">Select a Period Type</option>
            <?php       
                if($rowCount>0){
                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['period_type_id'].'">'.
                        $row['period_type_desc'].           
                        ' </option>';                
                    }
                }else{
                    echo '<option value="">Period type not available</option>';
                }           
            ?>  
    </select>
```

The HTML for the inputs I wish to update using the AJAX function below:

```
    <label>Start Date (Auto-generated):</label>
<input type="text" id="start_date" name="start_date" value = "" readonly>   
<br><br>
<label>End Date (Auto-generated):</label>
<input type="text" id="end_date" name="end_date" value = "" readonly>
```

And the AJAX function:

```
    function getNewP(){
        var id = $("#period_type_id").val();
        alert(id); //This fires ok
        if (id != '')
        {
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "get_period_nbrs.php",
                method:"POST",
                data: { id : id },
                dataType: "JSON",

                success: function(output) 
                {
                    $('#start_date').text(output.start_date);
                    $('#end_date').text(output.end_date);
                }
            });
        }else
        {
            alert("Please select a Period Type");
        }

}
```

Finally, the main PHP script:

```
<?php
include 'connect_db.php';

if (isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])){
    //echo $_POST[id];
    $sql =  "SELECT SUBSTRING(MAX(period_nbr),5,2)+1 AS nxt_sfx, 
                        MAX(start_date)+ 1 as start_date, MAX(end_date)+1 AS end_date  
                            FROM periods AS p 
                            INNER JOIN periodtypes AS pt on pt.period_type_id = p.period_type_id
                            WHERE p.period_type_id = '".$_POST['id']."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        if($result == true){
            $start_date = $row['start_date'];
            $end_date = $row['end_date'];
            $period_nbr_nxt_sfx = $row['nxt_sfx'];
            if ($period_nbr_nxt_sfx < 52 && $period_nbr_nxt_sfx != NULL){
                $output['start_date'] = $row['start_date'];
                $output['end_date'] = $row['end_date'];
                echo json_encode($output);
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: any error you are getting? check the errors on server and client side and post it.

Comment: There are no errors thrown up.

Comment: Could you post the content of `console.log(output)` in your `success()` function, please ?

Comment: It's worked now by changing the method in the success function from text() to val() as suggested by someone's earlier reply (which I can't see now to thank them).

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: Also, see about prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the right method to fill your inputs :

```
$('#start_date').text(output.start_date);
$('#end_date').text(output.end_date);
```

Should be :

```
$('#start_date').val(output.start_date);
$('#end_date').val(output.end_date);
```

Comment: I've changed the method to from text to val but it still doesn't work. The text method is in use in a few sites I've visited in trying to learn to resolve this. And it works there.

Comment: Syscall, your suggestion works now. I think the javascript file hadn't updated when I first tried to change the method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JSON needs a root key, try this:

```
print_r( "{\"data\": ".json_encode($output)."}" );
```

instead of

```
echo json_encode($output);
```